# beam.io.WriteToText add new line after each value - can it be removed?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My pipeline looks similar to the following:

```
parDo return list per processed line |  beam.io.WriteToText
```

beam.io.WriteToText adds a new line after each list element. How can I remove this new line and have the values separated by comma so I will be able to build CSV file

Any help is very appreciated!
Thanks,
eilalan

Answer (score 0):

To remove the newline char, you can use this:

```
beam.io.WriteToText(append_trailing_newlines=False)
```

But for adding commas between your values, there's no out-of-the-box feature on TextIO to convert to CSV. But, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46796204/9910124) for a user defined PTransform that can be applied to your PCollection in order to convert dictionary data into csv data.