# Is it possible to write without breaking line for each pcollection in Java?

Tags: java, apache-beam, spring-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I've just started using Java SDK Apache beam. 
As it is required to write files without breaking lines on elements, I'm trying to find a way to do it.

Looking at below, I kind of find it similar but still I can't find the equivalent option. 
[beam.io.WriteToText add new line after each value - can it be removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50913942/beam-io-writetotext-add-new-line-after-each-value-can-it-be-removed)

What I'm trying with is this.

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO.write()
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ```TextIO``` already covered that. Could you please tell us what issue are you having.

Comment: Thx for reply :) 
In short, how can I remove new lines to write for a whole PCollections?

Want is
```
ABC
```
rather than

```
A \n
B \n
C \n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An accumator which extends `CombineFn<InputT, AccumT, OutputT>` led it write concatenated string sets without breaking line.